# creating a tableau pie chart with no measures data

Tags: tableau-api, pie-chart

I have a table (as seen in link below), that has a system assessment that we conduct every year. The assessment is a series of 4 questions (or as we call them 'attributes') and there is only 3 possible outcomes.

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXIQE.png)

Using Tableau, I'd like to have the system as a filter (easy to do), and for each attribute build a pie chart. There are no measures that I capturing.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to know the power of LOD calculations in Tableau it is not that tough.  Walkthrough-

**Step-1** Create LOD calculated field for each Attribute as, `Attri_1_Measure`

```
{Fixed [Status of Attribute 1] : COUNT (sheet_name)}
```

**Step-2** Add `Attri_1_Measure` to angle, size and text measures,  `Status_of_attri1` to text and color.  You'll get your desired view.

**Step-3** Add System to filters, right click and add filters to context (very important step).

You can repeat these steps for each attribute.

Note: Beginning version 2020 of tableau there is no measure as `number of records`, but there is a sheet/data_table count measure therein.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Aliter: Easy solution:

Click on/select `number_of_records`/`count(sheet)` and also 'attribute_1`field in data pane and click`pie_chart`on`show_me` (ctrl +1) tool of tableau and pie chart will be created.